# Getting logs for a transaction on both servers on a Load balancer

Tags: linux, tomcat, logging, error-logging, aws-elb

I have an application deployed on 2 Tomcat servers, and exposed with an AWS classic Load Balancer. When a transaction request is sent to the Load balancer, I find the logs for that one transaction on both servers. I don't know if it is an application logging configuration or that is just how classic LBs work? Is it not supposed to be one transaction request per server? Can anyone please help to explain why this is happening?

I look at the logs on both servers with this command:
cat /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out | grep

Sometimes I find the transaction details on one server and then the stack trace for that transaction on the other server (in case of errors). When there are no errors, I see the transaction details on both servers.

Comment: When you say "A transaction request", do you mean a single HTTP request or a business transaction with multiple HTTP request involved?

Comment: A business transaction with multiple http requests